# Javascript handle string

Tags: javascript

I have very long string which I am trying to access in javascript, however I got following script error:

```
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' 
abc.htm, line 96 character 160
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. 
jquery-1.7.1.js, line 611 character 6
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. 
jquery-1.7.1.js, line 611 character 6
```

In my string almost all special characters are there like `' " ; ( ) [ ] . / ,` almost all, **which is coming through java controller and I am accessing it using expression language**. When I tested with simple string without any special character it is working fine.

So I am not getting idea which one is causing error and I can not test by removing one by one.

So is there any solution that it can treat as simple string in javascript? One thing I don't want to replace any of it with blank I want to treated as simple string.

Comment: if you have both ' and " I'm afraid you'll have to escape one of them, depending on how you wrap your string variable (or how you create it with new String())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the special characters

```
stringvalue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
```

Check it in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6BdUq/)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `escape(stringvalue)` function

else use the \ character to escape a character that has special meaning inside a regular expression.

To automate it, you could use this:

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

Comment: what for do you want it?

Comment: I just want to let you know that `escape` will encode the string and does not remove the special characters.

Comment: Still I am getting same, will replace work for `'` and `"` both?